# AngularJS interceptor only working for GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar, interceptor

i'm trying to use an Interceptor to intercep my ajax request, however it only works for `GET` request, I tried it with `POST` and `PUT` but noting seams to do the trick. Any idea ?
Here is how i create my interceptor

```
app.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', '$injector',
function ($q, $location, $injector) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            var AuthService = $injector.get('AuthService');
            console.log(AuthService.getCurrentUser(), AuthService.getCurrentUser().key);
            if(config.usingKey === true) config.headers['X-API-KEY'] = AuthService.getCurrentUser().key;
            if(config.beforeSend && typeof config.beforeSend == "function") config.beforeSend();
            return config;
        }
    };
}]);
```

I'm using this services to make a call

```
angular.module('myapp')
.service('EventService', ['$filter', '$http', 'CONFIG', function ($filter, $http, CONFIG) {
    this.create = function(params, beforeSend, usingkey) {
        if(usingkey == null) usingkey = true;
        return $http.put(CONFIG.DEV ? CONFIG.URL_API_DEV + "event" : CONFIG.URL_API + "event", {params: params, beforeSend: beforeSend, usingKey: usingkey})
    };
}]);
```

And finally I'm calling my service using this code.

```
 select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view, resourceObj) {
    EventService.create({}, function(){
        $('.status').find('i').removeClass("fa-check").addClass("fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch");
    }).then(function($data){
        $('.status').find('i').removeClass("fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch").addClass('fa-check');
        event.realid = $data.data.value.id;
        Calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
    }, function(err){
        $('.status').find('i').removeClass("fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch").addClass('fa-close').css({'color': 'red'});
        toastr.error(err);
    });
    $scope.$apply(); // The $apply is for another part of the code, it is required.
 }
```

Let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: For debuging purpose, try calling the EventService.create inside a $timeout.

Comment: Oh that would be a great idea actually, i'll try that.

Comment: @RafaelP.Miranda It did not worked, unfortunatly.

Comment: Show the code that registers the interceptor.

Comment: @georgeawg it's a simple push `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');`